# Can anyone recommend some good second hand camera stores in Japan?

Tags: lens, old-lenses, olympus

I recently purchased an OM-2n, which I've been really happy with. However, I am looking to pick up a few more lenses on my next trip to Japan. Does anyone have any recommendations on good second hand stores? I have visited the odd one when I've been there in the past but they're often tucked away and quite hard to find unless you know they're there.

Comment: Anywhere particular in Japan?

Comment: Sorry, should have specified that. Mainly Tokyo, Kyoto and Hiroshima. Anything along the way would work.

Comment: Would be great if someone could provide a reason for the -1, rather than just doing so. The question is a valid one. If it's not, please give me a reason why.

Answer (score 1):

Few years ago, I had friend of my in Japan and my idea was to buy Japan camera in Japan. But this was bad idea, because here prices very high. If you want buy Japan stuff, buy it in other country - my opinion. Better prices I am sure.

Comment: Is this second-hand equipment or new cameras? I definitely agree on new cameras, and there's also usually the issue of language compatability with some models.